# Why the Checkboxes remain selected(Gains previous user state) even after a new user is signed in

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

When I am signed in with new user details, it has to show fresh Activity containing Checkboxes. But, it is showing what last signed in user selected. Whenever I am signed in, I have to deselect the existing. How can I solve this

Here is my code

```
saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();

            if(mFirstCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                userMap.put("F1", "Compiler Design");
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).collection("Interests").document("Inter").set(userMap);
            }

            if(mSecondCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                userMap.put("F2", "Operating Systems");
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).collection("Interests").document("Inter").set(userMap);
            }

            if(mThirdCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                userMap.put("F3", "Software Engineering");
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).collection("Interests").document("Inter").set(userMap);
            }

            if(mFourthCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                userMap.put("F4", "MFCS");
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).collection("Interests").document("Inter").set(userMap);
            }   Intent setupIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
            startActivity(setupIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you please paste your code ??

Comment: xml or java code...???

Comment: paste your java code

Comment: show your code?

Comment: I have posted my code... Actually a part of code... Do you want me to post full code

Comment: would you please answer me @chandanicpatel

Comment: @Bunny ... i posted the code

Comment: yes please post full code so we can understand what you are doing exactly

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted your code regarding `setChecked()` on your CheckBoxes. Try to set `setChecked(false)` in your activiy's onCreate.

If you are restarting your activity, it might be saving and restoring all of the views inside it (as it does), and that may be why your check views are recovered.